# Create JPA EntityManager without persistence.xml configuration file

Tags: jpa, runtime, entitymanager, persistence.xml

Is there a way to initialize the `EntityManager` without a persistence unit defined? Can you give all the required properties to create an entity manager? I need to create the `EntityManager` from the user's specified values at runtime. Updating the `persistence.xml` and recompiling is not an option.

Any idea on how to do this is more than welcomed!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Is there a way to initialize the `EntityManager` without a persistence unit defined?

You should define **at least** one persistence unit in the `persistence.xml` deployment descriptor.

> Can you give all the required properties to create an `Entitymanager`?

- The name attribute is required. The other attributes and elements are optional. (JPA specification). So this should be more or less your minimal `persistence.xml` file:

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="[REQUIRED_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE]">
        SOME_PROPERTIES
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

> In Java EE environments, the `jta-data-source` and `non-jta-data-source` elements are used to specify **the global JNDI name of the JTA and/or non-JTA data source** to be used by the persistence provider.

So if your target Application Server supports JTA (JBoss, Websphere, GlassFish), your `persistence.xml` looks like:

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="[REQUIRED_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE]">
        <!--GLOBAL_JNDI_GOES_HERE-->
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If your target Application Server does not support JTA (Tomcat), your `persistence.xml` looks like:

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="[REQUIRED_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE]">
        <!--GLOBAL_JNDI_GOES_HERE-->
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myDS</non-jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If your data source is not bound to a global JNDI (for instance, outside a Java EE container), so you would usually define JPA provider, driver, url, user and password properties. **But** property name depends on the JPA provider. So, for Hibernate as JPA provider, your `persistence.xml` file will looks like:

```xml
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="[REQUIRED_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE]">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>br.com.persistence.SomeClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EmpServDB;create=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="APP"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="APP"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Transaction Type Attribute

> In general, in Java EE environments, a transaction-type of `RESOURCE_LOCAL` assumes that a non-JTA datasource will be provided. In a Java EE environment, if this element is not specified, the default is JTA. In a Java SE environment, if this element is not specified, a default of `RESOURCE_LOCAL` may be assumed.

- To insure the portability of a Java SE application, **it is necessary to explicitly list** the managed persistence classes that are included in the persistence unit (JPA specification)

> I need to create the `EntityManager` from the user's specified values at runtime

So use this:

```java
Map addedOrOverridenProperties = new HashMap();

// Let's suppose we are using Hibernate as JPA provider
addedOrOverridenProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);

Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(<PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME_GOES_HERE>, addedOrOverridenProperties);
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution, but run into problems, could you please check my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935394/how-to-externalize-properties-from-jpas-persistence-xml

Comment: But... the question was how to create a JPA EntityManager *without* persistence.xml.   This answer is good, but it's still using persistence.xml, right?

Comment: In JavaEE Environment, creating a EntityManagerFactory do they get managed by EJB/JPA?

Answer (score 28):

Yes you can without using any xml file using spring like this inside a @Configuration class (or its equivalent spring config xml):

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf(){
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", dbDriverClassName);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbConnectionURL);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser); //if needed

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.class); //If your using eclipse or change it to whatever you're using
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.yourpkg"); //The packages to search for Entities, line required to avoid looking into the persistence.xml
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName(SysConstants.SysConfigPU);
    emf.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    emf.setLoadTimeWeaver(new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver()); //required unless you know what your doing
    return emf;
}
```

Comment: What object is `properties`?

Comment: it is a simple java.util.Properties object

Answer (score 27):

Here's a solution without Spring.
Constants are taken from `org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings` :

```
entityManagerFactory = new HibernatePersistenceProvider().createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
            archiverPersistenceUnitInfo(),
            ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                    .put(JPA_JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_DRIVER)
                    .put(JPA_JDBC_URL, JDBC_URL)
                    .put(DIALECT, Oracle12cDialect.class)
                    .put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, CREATE)
                    .put(SHOW_SQL, false)
                    .put(QUERY_STARTUP_CHECKING, false)
                    .put(GENERATE_STATISTICS, false)
                    .put(USE_REFLECTION_OPTIMIZER, false)
                    .put(USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, false)
                    .put(USE_QUERY_CACHE, false)
                    .put(USE_STRUCTURED_CACHE, false)
                    .put(STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, 20)
                    .build());

entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

And the infamous `PersistenceUnitInfo`

```
private static PersistenceUnitInfo archiverPersistenceUnitInfo() {
    return new PersistenceUnitInfo() {
        @Override
        public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
            return "ApplicationPersistenceUnit";
        }

        @Override
        public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
            return "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider";
        }

        @Override
        public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
            return PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
            try {
                return Collections.list(this.getClass()
                                            .getClassLoader()
                                            .getResources(""));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Properties getProperties() {
            return new Properties();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer transformer) {

        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot since it helped me to avoid using the overhead of using arquillian in some test cases!

Comment: hi, how do i know it is safe to ignore the passed argument to addClassTransformer?

Comment: @user2297550 This will likely depend on your usage, so the code base you're working on may need it.

Answer (score 20):

I was able to create an `EntityManager` with Hibernate and PostgreSQL purely using Java code (with a Spring configuration) the following:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();

    dataSource.setDatabaseName( "mytestdb" );
    dataSource.setUser( "myuser" );
    dataSource.setPassword("mypass");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties(){
    final Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop" );

    return properties;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory( DataSource dataSource, Properties hibernateProperties ){
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource( dataSource );
    em.setPackagesToScan( "net.initech.domain" );
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter( new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() );
    em.setJpaProperties( hibernateProperties );
    em.setPersistenceUnitName( "mytestdomain" );
    em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    em.afterPropertiesSet();

    return em.getObject();
}
```

The call to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` is **essential** since otherwise the factory never gets built, and then `getObject()` returns `null` and you are chasing after `NullPointerException`s all day long. >:-(

It then worked with the following code:

```
PageEntry pe = new PageEntry();
pe.setLinkName( "Google" );
pe.setLinkDestination( new URL( "http://www.google.com" ) );

EntityTransaction entTrans = entityManager.getTransaction();
entTrans.begin();
entityManager.persist( pe );
entTrans.commit();
```

Where my entity was this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page_entries")
public class PageEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String linkName;
    private URL linkDestination;

    // gets & setters omitted
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative for Hibernate.

Answer (score 8):

With plain JPA, assuming that you have a `PersistenceProvider` implementation (e.g. Hibernate), you can use the [PersistenceProvider#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory-javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo-java.util.Map-) method to bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory` without needing a `persistence.xml`.

However, it's annoying that you have to implement the `PersistenceUnitInfo` interface, so you are better off using Spring or Hibernate which both support bootstrapping JPA without a `persistence.xml` file:

```
this.nativeEntityManagerFactory = provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
    this.persistenceUnitInfo, 
    getJpaPropertyMap()
);
```

Where the [PersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) is implemented by the Spring-specific [MutablePersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/MutablePersistenceUnitInfo.html) class.

Comment: Using `MutablePersistenceUnitInfo` does not work as some methods [throw UnsupportedOperationException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/MutablePersistenceUnitInfo.java#L272-L274). Also the [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/11/26/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/) mentionned is a bit outdated : `getPersistenceUnitRootUrl` cannot return null otherwise Hibernate does not scan the classpath (Hibernate 5.2.8).

Comment: I was a bit wrong, the article is not outdated in that regard as the code is passing a list of entities and does not use package scanning. However for auto entity scanning it is necessary to implement either `getPersistenceUnitRootUrl ` or `getJarFileUrls`. The later is sown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42372648/48136

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus JPA that I use also has a way of doing this [in its docs](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/persistence.html#persistenceunit_dynamic). No need for Spring, or ugly implementation of `PersistenceUnitInfo`.

Simply do as follows

```
import org.datanucleus.metadata.PersistenceUnitMetaData;
import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManagerFactory;

PersistenceUnitMetaData pumd = new PersistenceUnitMetaData("dynamic-unit", "RESOURCE_LOCAL", null);
pumd.addClassName("mydomain.test.A");
pumd.setExcludeUnlistedClasses();
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:nucleus");
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "sa");
pumd.addProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
pumd.addProperty("datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll", "true");

EntityManagerFactory emf = new JPAEntityManagerFactory(pumd, null);
```