# Difference between JPA properties in entity Manager Factory and Persistence Unit

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I observed there are two places for placing jpa properties:

1. entity manager factory in spring context:

[image]

2. persistence unit in persistence.xml:

[image]

I want to ask what are the difference of them. And which takes precedence?

Comment: Set the same thing in both files but with different value and see whats in effect

Comment: check out these documentations  for persistence.xml https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit and  Entitymanager https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html  or these other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989672/create-jpa-entitymanager-without-persistence-xml-configuration-file